# lexicographical order in reverse order

Tags: python

I need to make a code that sorts a list of words and puts them in lexicographical order from reverse. For example, given the list `["harry", "harra", harrb"]` I need a way to reverse each word so the list becomes `["yrrah", "arrah","brrah"]`. Then I need to sort it by lexicographical order and reverse it back to its original order. So it would look like `["harra", "harrb", "harry"]`. I'm taking words from a file `ifile` but for this code I'm only ordering words with a certain number of letters "n".

Here is my code so far:

```
def getRhymeSortedCount(n,ifile,file):
    word_list = []
    for word in ifile:
        if len(word) == n:
            word_list.append(word.strip())
    arr = word_list
    arr.sort(key = lambda x : x[::-1])
    ofile.write("\n".join(word_list))
```

It correctly orders the words by their last letter, but isn't taking the words with number of letters = "n" how can i change my len statement to grab only the words with n letters?

Comment: Strip the spaces before getting the length. Right now `len` includes the newline at the end.

Comment: can you show me how to implement that?

Comment: Just insert `word = word.strip()` before the `if`. Then you can also just `append(word)` later.

Comment: nvm figured it out thank yOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the given example

```
list1=["harry", "harra", "harrb"]
```

Using list comprehension get the reverse order of the `list1` which would look like this

```
list1=[x[::-1] for x in list1]
```

Now

```
list1=['yrrah','arrah','brrah']
```

Using `sorted()` method we can sort the `list1`, which would look like this

```
p=sorted(list1)
```

Now,

```
p=['arrah','brrah','yrrah']
```

Using list comprehension get the reverse order of the list1 which would look like this

```
list1=[x[::-1] for x in list1]
```

Now,

```
list1=['harra','harrb','harry']
```

So, this is one way to get the things done as per your condition.